# Is there any way to share a card view which contains a picture to other social apps?

Tags: java, android

[image]
is there any way I can share this card view to WhatsApp, Instagram or other social media apps
[image]
[![this is the card view that gets the selected picture from the gallery that user want to share and shows the image , its name and its size I want to share the card view when I check the checkbox in it … please help me and do pardon me for language if I'm wrong]
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBx1T.png)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBx1T.png)

[image: All I want is to share these yellow cards thank you in advance.]

Comment: This sounds like an android question. Especially since it is regarding the environment more than the programming language.

Comment: yes this question is about android development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don`t think so there is any way that you can share a complete card you can share images and text separately.

For Whatsapp you can share image and add text to that msg that contains image.